# What C# class do I need to deserialize a REST result with sub-types

Tags: c#, rest

If this is the REST result:

```
[ {
  "sessionId" : "232e3ef6-eb80-413e-bce0-ebb167bf90d0",
  "instanceId" : "6070f583-c2aa-4a1f-8541-1d0b22e365fe",
  "clientId" : "com.whatever",
  "deviceId" : "abac87cca",
  "document" : {
    "nameOfHolder" : "SQUARE PANTS",
    "dateOfExpiry" : "161010",
    "features" : [ "DCA" ],
    "typegroups" : [ 1, 2 ]
  }
} ]
```

... what would a C# class look like that I can read the `document` sub-part successfully with?

At the moment I am reading it in using `HttpClient` and `Content.ReadAsAsync` successfully, but only if I miss out the "document" part:

```
public partial class ScanListItem
{
    public string SessionId { get; set; }
    public string InstanceId { get; set; }
    public string ClientId { get; set; }
    public string DeviceId { get; set; }

    // How do I represent the "document" here?
}
```

I've tried using a Dictionary like this:

```
public Dictionary<string, string> Document{ get; set; }
```

... which works until it tries to parse the "features" element - I think because `features` is an array (`Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: [. Path '[0].document.features.`)

**Here's what I'd like to do - is this possible:**
Represent them directly by name, something akin to this:

```
public string DocumentNameOfHolder { get; set; }
```

(when I try this it the field remains blank)

Comment: http://json2csharp.com/

Comment: Ha! Yes I've looked at that, but my REST service isn't public and so I need to add a key in the HTTP headers to try it :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about this?

```
public class Document
{
    public string NameOfHolder { get; set; }
    public string DateOfExpiry { get; set; }
    public List<string> Features { get; set; }
    public List<int> Typegroups { get; set; }
}

public class ScanListItem
{
    public string SessionId { get; set; }
    public string InstanceId { get; set; }
    public string ClientId { get; set; }
    public string DeviceId { get; set; }
   public Document document { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Ah so simple. Now I feel silly. But happy too. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You really have two options.

You can use a Dictionary where the value is an object, because then it can store anything you give it. e.g.

```
public Dictionary<string, object> Document{ get; set; }
```

But really the proper way would be using a sub document class like so.

```
public partial class ScanListItem
{
    public string SessionId { get; set; }
    public string InstanceId { get; set; }
    public string ClientId { get; set; }
    public string DeviceId { get; set; }
    public Document Document {get;set;}
}

public class Document
{
    public string NameOfHolder {get;set;}
    public List<string> Features {get;set;}
    //Other properties here. 
}
```

You can see a .net Fiddle here on how it works : https://dotnetfiddle.net/6IsDiN

Comment: Your dictionary example doesn't use "object", but I understand - thank you.

Comment: Woops! Sorry. Fixed :)

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of libraries for working with JSON. One of the most notable is [Json.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com).

Here is an example of seriliazing and the *deserializing* an object from their [documentation](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializingJSON.htm):

```
Product product = new Product();

product.Name = "Apple";
product.ExpiryDate = new DateTime(2008, 12, 28);
product.Price = 3.99M;
product.Sizes = new string[] { "Small", "Medium", "Large" };

string output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(product);
//{
//  "Name": "Apple",
//  "ExpiryDate": "2008-12-28T00:00:00",
//  "Price": 3.99,
//  "Sizes": [
//    "Small",
//    "Medium",
//    "Large"
//  ]
//}

Product deserializedProduct = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Product>(output);
```

As long as you have C# classes that align with what you are looking for, you could do something like this:

```
Session sess = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Session>(restOutputString);
Document doc = sess.Document;
```